# genymotion unable to connect to your Virtual Device?

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I installed genymotion v2.2.2 and Virtual Box v4.3.14
 When I start the genymotion device, It showed "Unable to connect to your virtual Device", I do not know how to solve it, please help me. Thank you
 here is my Image. I Start device in virtual box and it run without problem, But can not start in Genymotion

i.stack.imgur.com/8Zg6y.jpg

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows both VirtualBox and Genymotion windows open at the same time.  You shouldn't do that. What happens when you close VirtualBox entirely and launch only from the Genymotion launcher?